# Issue regarding form on Django 1.5

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

This is the scenario: I have a form with many field filled with some his own data and the user can change them.

In this form I collect 3 kind of data:

1. the first type of data are user data,
2. the second type of data are user personal data and
3. the third type of data are user work data.

Work data and personal data are binding to user data using a foreign key.

When the user clicks submit, my view collect this data from the request and send them to a view.

This is the problem:
this 3 type of data already have a model and a modelform (I used it in another part of this website),

```
class User(models.Model):
   username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
   password = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
   confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class PersonalData(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(AtgUser, primary_key=True)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   surname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   address = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)

class WorkData(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(AtgUser, primary_key=True)
   companyname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

And their related modelforms:

```
class Form1(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
      model = user.User

class Form2(ModelForm):
   class Meta:
      model = user.PersonalData
      exclude = 'user'

class Form3(ModelForm):
   class Meta:
      model = user.WorkData
      exclude = 'user'
```

But now I must use a new form that includes all the data like this:

```
 class Bigform(Forms.form):
   username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
   password = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   surname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   address = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
   companyname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

so:

*When I get my request in the view, How can I extract part of the collected data in Bigform and put this data in their own modelform or model in order to update this data in my Database?*

I thought of extract some field from Bigform in order to fill an already exist model or model form.

*Is this the correct way?*

Suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is quite unclear. If you have modelforms for the three models, why don't you just use them?\

Comment: Because I must do it in this way...   in this html page I have a form with data that I already have in other modelforms and model. I need to create a unique big form with all the data I need in order to submit it and process the collected data later in the view.

Comment: But you can do that by using all three existing modelforms in the same page, using a prefix for each one, and process them all in the same view. No need to repeat yourself.

Comment: How I can receive data from a form in a view and put this data into other form?  Please Daniel, Can you explain it to me ?

Comment: What? I don't understand the question. Just use those three forms in your view. Don't create one super-form, just use the three you have.

Comment: in my html page I have only one submit button that submit BigForm. In my view how can i use this 3 modelform? how can i fill this 3 modelform with the data collected from Bigform?

Comment: You just put all three modelforms within the same form tag.